# Get data from json file without index in php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file like this

```
[
{
    "item_id": "342",
    "item_title": "James"
  },
{
    "item_id": "374",
    "item_title": "Fred"
  }
]
```

And I would like to get the item_title in PHP but using the item_id.

How would I go about this?

I have

```
$item_id = 374;
$url = 'file.json'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$items = json_decode($data);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) if you know that key will always exist

```
echo $items[array_search($item_id,array_column($items,'item_id'))]['item_title'];
```

https://3v4l.org/Qddcj

Otherwise go for ***functional approach***

```
$items = json_decode($data,true);

function getItemTitle($array,$item_id){
    $key = array_search($item_id,array_column($array,'item_id'));
    if($key !==false && isset($array[$key]['item_title'])){
        return $array[$key]['item_title'];
    }else{
        return "no title found for given id ".$item_id;
    }

}

echo getItemTitle($items,$item_id);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/ikKWY

***In case if same id can be repeated multiple time***

```
$items = json_decode($json,true); 
foreach($items as $value){
    if($value['item_id']==$item_id){
        echo $value['item_title'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/7oPHk

Comment: Great.. your answer is always good with minimum code and your answer is improve my knowledge.. +1

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using the getItemTitle function more often in your code, I would suggest to convert the "non-indexed" json array to an indexed one. Using such one will be much faster and more handy. Of course, it depends on how often the search for title occures inyour code and how large is the json/array in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Some explanation: you should use `foreach loop` with `if` condition

Here is the sample code

```
<?php
$json='[
{
    "item_id": "342",
    "item_title": "James"
  },
{
    "item_id": "374",
    "item_title": "Fred"
  }
]';
$item_id = 374;

$items = json_decode($json); 
//print_r($items);
foreach($items as $value){
    if($value->item_id==$item_id){
        echo $value->item_title;
    }
}
```

You can check the desired [output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04055871d86a4d885c05699c8aa30c2ac35893b6)